# How to find the right string table in an ELF file?

Tags: elf

Writing a small program to retrieve some infos from an ELF file, I have some problems finding the right string table:

`objdump` prints something like

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
...
  [11] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 00119c 000680 10     12  45  4
  [12] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 00181c 000433 00      0   0  1
  [13] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 001c4f 00008e 00      0   0  1
```

Now `.strtab` contains strings from symbol names like `"main"`, whereas `.shstrtab` contains strings for section names from section headers (sh).

Hence to discriminate between the two `STRTAB`'s, I have to get the section name first, but to get the name of the sections, I have to know which of either `STRTAB`'s is named `.shstrtab`, so I am running in circles...

`.strtab` and `.shstrtab` have the same flags etc. so how do I find the section names without already knowing the section names?

---

**Notes:**

- I am using this documentation: [man 5](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)
- In `.symtab`, the `sh_link` field contains the index of the associated strtab, but for other sectons (NOTEs specifically), the `sh_link` field is empty.

Answer (score 1):

In the ELF header, there is a field `e_shstrndx` which holds the section header table index of the entry associated with the section name string table, or `SHN_UNDEF`, if the file has no such section.